# DOT error while using OWLviz in Protege 4.0

Tags: protege, osx-yosemite

I am using Protege version 4.0(Build 115) on OS X Yosemite Version 10.10.4. While using OWLviz in Protege, I am getting a DOT error. I already installed Graphviz for OS X but its still not working. Can you suggest me which version of Graphviz I should use? And What are the step to install it?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the path is set to correct DOT file, and then restart.